# Android Fused Location Api is not using GPS even with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am developing a tracking application for buses, I need to use GPS only, I followed this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) , however it only use network location not GPS even when using PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY !!

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

- My phone's location priority is high accuracy.
- GPS is enabled
- both fine and coarse permission are used
- the result are not accurate at all
- when using Google maps application, the GPS icon appears and the location gets more accurate

Comment: Make sure your phone's location priority is high accuracy as well

Comment: 1. Fused provider will not enable GPS for you(if user dissable it) 2. Fused Provider will not add the proper permissions for you ... 3. if results are accurate - then you shouldn't even bother about this ...

Comment: @mray190 it is already

Comment: @AhmadBassiouny we did some testing with the FusedLocation API and whilst it may be accurate for general location applications it is not accurate enough for real time tracking